# Rails route executing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing

I have route in rails that is executing twice per click.  First the route is as follows - (it is the print_cert route in the collection that is executing twice):

```
 resources :acd_certificates, only: [:edit, :update] do
    collection do
      get :print_cert, defaults: { format: 'pdf' }
    end
  end
```

And it is called from an edit form:

```
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit "Save Certificate", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <%= link_to print_cert_acd_certificates_path, class: "btn btn-primary" do %>
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print"></span> Print
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'Cancel', @client, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
```

No other route in this controller is reacting the same way.  There is no javascript on the form (and the form is not a partial) or in a separate js or coffee file.  The application does utilize jQuery in several locations, but not anywhere in the add_certificates unit.

I stripped all code out of the controller method print_cert and it still calls twice.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**
Add the log output:

```
Started GET "/acd_certificates/print_cert" for 73.48.173.116 at 2015-10-01 22:32:36 +0000
Processing by AcdCertificatesController#print_cert as PDF
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Sent file /home/ubuntu/workspace/tmp/pdfs/b6cda84f-da89-460d-976a-af863def9161.pdf (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 186ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started GET "/acd_certificates/print_cert" for 73.48.173.116 at 2015-10-01 22:32:37 +0000
Processing by AcdCertificatesController#print_cert as PDF
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Sent file /home/ubuntu/workspace/tmp/pdfs/b1348c24-bec7-442c-8b1f-0927e82ffe93.pdf (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 188ms (ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: Do you have this issue with any other route in your application?  Also how do you know it's executing twice (i.e., do you see that in your logs)?

Comment: It does show in the logs as executing twice. So far as I can see, no other route has the issue.

Comment: Well, I think the time I had this before it was related to having done some custom changes to the rails ubiquitous javascript support (causing the fire event to fire twice).  Have you done anything to your overall javascript support out of the ordinary?  Just to be baseline your install, what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: rails 4.2.3  and I have a suspicion that javascript is to blame somewhere as well.  I really haven't changed anything but I will dig deeper in that direction.

Comment: Could you please show the log where it fire twice?

Comment: EDIT added log output

Comment: I don't have a log to share per se (it was something I addressed long ago), but if I recall I found it by using my browser dev tools (I use Chrome) and stepped through the js (can be tedious).  If you have a suspicion about any related js, just put in console.log statement and see if you see it doubling up.

Comment: I don't know that this would help, but you can try adding a Rails.logger trace statement in the controller action to write the params to your rails log.  I don't think it'll tell you anything you don't already expect, but it would confirm what Rails is seeing submitted.   To trace above that you could monkey patch Rack for lower level detail, but that's not my first suspicion; instead I'd start client side first since that's probably more likely to reveal the behavior.  If you really want to try the Rack idea though here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/betesh/275c55abe7436417177b.

Answer (score 0):

OK as suspected it was related to JS and the use of turbo links.  I added data-no-turbolink to the link for printing that was calling twice and problem solved.  A good thing to remember with JS. I had no JS added to this form and yet it carried through from the index form from which it was called even though it was from a different unit.

Thanks rdnewman!!